# Apex mixed formatting (currency and number) in a table with repeat logic

Tags: visualforce, email, email-template

I've tried multiple solutions I've found here, but none are *quite* what I'm dealing with and thus my guesses at how to slice & dice the format inputs are failing. Below I have a VF email template that runs down a list of child rows to populate a **table**. It's come to my attention that the formatting is goofy - we need all the "currency" columns to display 000,000.00 format (notice I already have dynamic currency code) and the last column for Quantity to just display commas.

Currently there are no commas, and only a SINGLE place after the decimal - which even by itself is a weird default. Any help greatly appreciated!!

```
            <table border="0" >
              <tr >
                 <th>Action</th>
                 <th>Product Code</th>
                 <th>Product Name</th>
                 <th>End User Price</th>
                 <th>List Price</th>
                 <th>Target Price</th>
                 <th>Max Discount Price</th>                                  
                 <th>Annual Kit Qty / Units</th>
              </tr>
              <apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.Quote_to_Contract_Product__r}">
                <tr>
                  <td><a href="{!LEFT($CurrentPage.URL,FIND('/',$CurrentPage.URL,9))}{!cx.id}">View</a></td> 
                  <td> {!cx.Product_Code__c}</td>
                  <td> {!cx.Product__r.Name}</td>
                  <td> {!cx.CurrencyIsoCode} {!cx.End_User_Price_per_Kit__c}</td>
                  <td> {!cx.CurrencyIsoCode} {!cx.SYS_List_Price__c}</td>
                  <td> {!cx.CurrencyIsoCode} {!cx.SYS_Price_Floor_AE__c}</td>
                  <td> {!cx.CurrencyIsoCode} {!cx.SYS_Price_Floor_RD__c}</td>
                  <td> {!cx.Quantity__c}</td>
                </tr>
              </apex:repeat>                
            </table>
```

The current output:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Visualforce has a way to specify formatting using [`<apex:outputText>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputText.htm).

You specify a format in the `<apex:outputText>` tag, and then include an `<apex:param>` tag between the start and end tags (instead of using `<apex:outputText />`)

```html
<apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.Quote_to_Contract_Product__r}">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="{!LEFT($CurrentPage.URL,FIND('/',$CurrentPage.URL,9))}{!cx.id}">View</a></td> 
        <td> {!cx.Product_Code__c}</td>
        <td> {!cx.Product__r.Name}</td>
        <td> {!cx.CurrencyIsoCode} {!cx.End_User_Price_per_Kit__c}</td>
        <td> {!cx.CurrencyIsoCode} {!cx.SYS_List_Price__c}</td>
        <td> {!cx.CurrencyIsoCode} {!cx.SYS_Price_Floor_AE__c}</td>
        <td> {!cx.CurrencyIsoCode} {!cx.SYS_Price_Floor_RD__c}</td>
        <td> {!cx.Quantity__c}</td>
    </tr>
</apex:repeat>
```

becomes

```html
<apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.Quote_to_Contract_Product__r}">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="{!LEFT($CurrentPage.URL,FIND('/',$CurrentPage.URL,9))}{!cx.id}">View</a></td> 
        <td> {!cx.Product_Code__c}</td>
        <td> {!cx.Product__r.Name}</td>
        <td> 
            <apex:outputText value="{!cx.CurrencyIsoCode} {0, number, ###,###.00}">
                <apex:param value="{!cx.End_User_Price_per_Kit__c}"/>
            </apex:outputText>
        </td>
        <td> 
            <apex:outputText value="{!cx.CurrencyIsoCode} {0, number, ###,###.00}">
                <apex:param value="{!cx.SYS_List_Price__c}"/>
            </apex:outputText>
        </td>
        <td> 
            <apex:outputText value="{!cx.CurrencyIsoCode} {0, number, ###,###.00}">
                <apex:param value="{!cx.Price_Floor_AE__c}"/>
            </apex:outputText>
        </td>
        <td> 
            <apex:outputText value="{!cx.CurrencyIsoCode} {0, number, ###,###.00}">
                <apex:param value="{!cx.Price_Floor_RD__c}"/>
            </apex:outputText>
        </td>
        <td> 
            <apex:outputText value="{!cx.CurrencyIsoCode} {0, number, ###,###}">
                <apex:param value="{!cx.Quantity}"/>
            </apex:outputText>
        </td>
    </tr>
</apex:repeat>
```

The `{0, number, ###,###.##}` bit is the formatting string, and it follows the Java `MessageFormat` syntax.

- 0 = the argument index number (if you had multiple `<apex:param>`, the first would be index 0, the second index 1, etc...
- number = the format type (one of number, date, time, choice)
- ###,###.## = the subformat pattern (or format style)

You *might* be able to get away with `{0, number, currency}` (except for the quantity, which would be `{0, number, integer}`), but using a subformat pattern gives you more control.

Took a little bit of digging to unearth the characters you can use in a [decimal subformat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) pattern, reproducing here...

| Symbol | Location | Localized? | Meaning |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Number | Yes | Digit (always present) |
| # | Number | Yes | Digit, zero shows as absent |
| . | Number | Yes | Decimal separator or monetary decimal separator |
| - | Number | Yes | Minus sign |
| , | Number | Yes | Grouping separator |
| E | Number | Yes | Separates mantissa and exponent in scientific notation. Need not be quoted in prefix or suffix. |
| ; | Subpattern boundary | Yes | Separates positive and negative subpatterns |
| % | Prefix or suffix | Yes | Multiply by 100 and show as percentage |
| \u2030 | Prefix or suffix | Yes | Multiply by 1000 and show as per mille value |
| ¤ (\u00A4) | Prefix or suffix | No | Currency sign, replaced by currency symbol. If doubled, replaced by international currency symbol. If present in a pattern, the monetary decimal separator is used instead of the decimal separator. |
| ' | Prefix or suffix | No | Used to quote special characters in a prefix or suffix, for example, "'#'#" formats 123 to "#123". To create a single quote itself, use two in a row: "# o''clock". |

The difference between `{0, number, ###,###.##}` and `{0, number, 000,000.00}` would be that given an input of 1234.50

- the first would display as "1,234.5"
- the second would display as "001,234.50"

A "0" in the subpattern format causes that digit/decimal to always be displayed.
A "#" in the subpattern format removes leading and trailing 0s.

So following that, `{0, number, ###,###.00}` would display "1,234.50"

For reference, here is the VFP I used to test/confirm this behavior

```html
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:outputText value="{!account.Name} {0, number, ###,###.##}">
        <apex:param value="{!1234.50}"/>
    </apex:outputText>
    <apex:outputText value="{!account.Name} {0, number, 000,000.00}">
        <apex:param value="{!1234.50}"/>
    </apex:outputText>
    <apex:outputText value="{!account.Name} {0, number, ###,###.00}">
        <apex:param value="{!1234.50}"/>
    </apex:outputText>
    <apex:outputText value="{!account.Name} {0, number, currency}">
        <apex:param value="{!1234.50}"/>
    </apex:outputText>
    <apex:outputText value="{!account.Name} {0, number, integer}">
        <apex:param value="{!1234.50}"/>
    </apex:outputText>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Note: I haven't tested this with a Visualforce Email Template, just visualforce rendered on-platform in a Visualforce page.

Comment: Thanks so much, yeah I eventually figured out that the formatting needed to be repeated, and inside each TD, and wrapped around the specific field.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would come back and share in case it was ever useful for anyone else - this includes currency formatted columns along other columns that are just text or numbers, and the last column is also right-justified.

```
    <table border="0" >
          <tr >
             <th>Action</th>
             <th>Product Code</th>
             <th>Product Name</th>
             <th>End User Price</th>
             <th>List Price</th>
             <th>Target Price</th>
             <th>Max Discount Price</th>                                  
             <th> <div align="right"> Annual Kit Qty / Units </div> </th>
          </tr>
          <apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.Quote_to_Contract_Product__r}">

            <tr>
              <td><a href="{!LEFT($CurrentPage.URL,FIND('/',$CurrentPage.URL,9))}{!cx.id}">View</a></td>                                     
              <td> {!cx.Product_Code__c}</td>
              <td> {!cx.Product__r.Name}</td>
              <td> {!cx.CurrencyIsoCode}&nbsp; <apex:outputText value="{0,number,#,##0.00}"><apex:param value="{!cx.End_User_Price_per_Kit__c}"/> </apex:outputtext> </td>
              <td> {!cx.CurrencyIsoCode}&nbsp; <apex:outputText value="{0,number,#,##0.00}"><apex:param value="{!cx.SYS_List_Price__c}"/> </apex:outputtext> </td>
              <td> {!cx.CurrencyIsoCode}&nbsp; <apex:outputText value="{0,number,#,##0.00}"><apex:param value="{!cx.SYS_Price_Floor_AE__c}"/> </apex:outputtext> </td>
              <td> {!cx.CurrencyIsoCode}&nbsp; <apex:outputText value="{0,number,#,##0.00}"><apex:param value="{!cx.SYS_Price_Floor_RD__c}"/> </apex:outputtext> </td>
              <td> <div align="right"> <apex:outputText value=" {0,number,#,##0}"><apex:param value="{!cx.Quantity__c}"/> </apex:outputtext> </div> </td>                
            </tr>
            
          </apex:repeat>         
        </table>
```